# Problems receiving Facebook chat messages from mobile clients

Tags: facebook, messaging

I've been experiencing problems with receiving Facebook messages within the integrated Facebook chat on my WP8 device from an iOS device running the Facebook Messenger application. I just don't get  this messages whilst I can see them in the messages page on the Facebook site on my PC.

When the other person uses the Facebook website on their PC I am able to receive the messages and get them immediately.

Is there anybody else who has experienced this problems, too and got this to work in any way? Or is it a known problem with no workaround existing?

Comment: I am using Windows Phone 7.8 and sometimes I don't get messages pushed to my phone and sometimes I get them late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Messenger is out in the Windows Phone Store.

1. Install [Facebook Messenger](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=3219d30d-4a23-4f58-a91c-c44b04e6a0c7)
2. Disable the built-in Facebook chat.
3. Disable Messages Notifications in the Facebook app.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with Microsoft Live(`Messaging` service). The connection to facebook will persist only ping/pong between facebook and client(`Live`) taking place. `Messaging`'s background is not much effective, that why you can't get all the messages.

Comment: I believe NK is correct about the issue. I believe you should still get toast notifications from the official Facebook app though if you install that. That's at least what I've noticed in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get Facebook messaging integration to work onn my WP7.5 phone, simply by turning it on at Settings > Applications > Messaging > Facebook Chat = On.

I'm not sure if this is relevant to your question about the other party using an iOS device running the Facebook Messenger application, but it might be helpful for anyone who didn't realize it could be disabled by this toggle.